# nodejs - angular BDD in real browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am developing an application by using nodeJs + yo angular-fullstck and my starting point is the BDD and TDD.

After a research over various sites i decided to do this by using [cucumber-js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-cucumberjs) and Jasmin respectively over karma runner.

All the tests were red, I made them green and I thought that I am ready to go for real tests.
My problems seems to be focused more on cucumber-js rather on Jasmine.

I am trying to setup some tests that would open a real browser (not a headless one) and unfortunately this seems to be harder than I thought.

Could someone give me some hints of how to do this?

Is the karma-cucumberjs a correct choise for what I want to achive?

Thanks

Comment: When you set up your config in Karma did you specify your browsers? Karma should open all of the browsers listed in your karam.config file.

Comment: Yes I specify them. The title of my post might be mislead. The problem is that I cannot request a specific page for doing relevant tests. For i.e. something like "browser().get('some page')". I am new in TDD and BDD and I might also be in a wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite test runner which launches a full browser session is [Protractor](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing). It was simple to setup and I haven't had much trouble with it yet.

The tests I write are still in Jasmine and an example one looks like this.

```
describe "Angular Test Scaffold", ->
  it "displays my GitHub name", ->
    browser.get("app/index.html").then ->
      expect(element(By.css("#githubName")).getText()).toBe("Test user")
```

I wrote a little about how I setup my first project with protractor on [my github site](http://eerwitt.github.io/2014/06/28/tdd-with-angular/). I hope it will be useful.